# A Process accessing memory outside of allocated region

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, processor

Assume a process is allocated a certain region of virtual memory.
How will the processor react if the process happens to access a memory region outside this allocation region?

Does the processor kill the process? Or does it raise a Fault?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Processes are not really allocated a certain region of virtual memory. They are allocated physical frames that they can access using virtual memory. Processes have virtual access to all virtual memory available.

When a high level language is compiled, it is placed in an executable. This executable is a file format which specifies several things among which is the virtual memory in use by the program. When the OS launches that executable, it will allocate certain physical pages to the newly created process. These pages contain the actual code. The OS needs to set up the page tables so that the virtual addresses that the process uses are translated to the right position in memory (the right physical addresses).

When a process attempts to jump nowhere at a virtual address it shouldn't jump to, several things can happen. It is undefined behavior.

As stated on osdev.org (https://wiki.osdev.org/Paging):

> A page fault exception is caused when a process is seeking to access an area of virtual memory that is not mapped to any physical memory, when a write is attempted on a read-only page, when accessing a PTE or PDE with the reserved bit or when permissions are inadequate.
>
> The CPU pushes an error code on the stack before firing a page fault exception. The error code must be analyzed by the exception handler to determine how to handle the exception. The bottom 3 bits of the exception code are the only ones used, bits 3-31 are reserved.

It really depends on the language you used and several factors come into play. For example, in assembly, if you try to jump in RAM to a random virtual address. Several things can happen.

1. If you jump into an allocated page, then the page could contain anything. It could as well contain zeroes. If it contain zeroes, then the process will keep executing the instructions until it reaches a page which isn't present in RAM and trigger a page fault. Or it could as well just end up executing a jmp to somewhere else in RAM and in the end trigger page fault.
2. If you jump into a page which has the present bit not set (unallocated page), then the CPU will trigger a page fault immediately. Since the page is not allocated, it will not magically become allocated. The OS needs to take action. If the page was supposed to be accessed by the process then maybe it was swapped to the hard disk and the OS needs to swap it back in RAM. If it wasn't supposed to be accessed (like in this case), the OS needs to kill the process (and it does). The OS knows the process should not access a page by looking at its memory map for that process. It should not just blindly allocate a page to a process which jumps nowhere. If the process needs more memory during execution it can ask the OS properly using system calls.
3. If you jump to a virtual address which, once translated by the MMU using the page tables, lands in RAM in kernel mode code (supervisor code), the CPU will trigger a page fault with supervisor and present error codes (1  0  1).

The OS uses 2 levels of permission (0 and 3). Thus all user mode processes run with permission 3. Nothing prevents one user process from accessing the memory and the code of another process except the way the page tables are set up. The page tables are often not filled up completely. If you jump to a random virtual address, anything can happen. The virtual address can be translated to anything.